# Controlador laravel para recibir datos desde ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Estoy intentado insertar datos desde un Ajax pero me da error HTTP500 supongo que es del controlador y me surge la duda de que modificaciones necesita el controlador para recibir los datos correctamente??

**Controlador**

```
public function controladorprueba(Request $request)
    {

        $product = Product::create($request->all());

        return Response::json($product);

    }
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('submit', '#formularioprueba', function() {

      //Obtengo datos formulario.
      var data = $(this).serialize();

      //AJAX.
      $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
          url  : "{{ route('products.prueba1') }}",
          data:  data,

          success:function(data) {
              $('#respuesta').html(data).fadeIn();
          }
      });
      return false;
 });
});
    </script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('products/prueba1', 'ProductController@controladorprueba')->name('products.controladorprueba');
```

Comment: El error 500 pueden darse por muchos casos, revisa tu log y postea el error para poder ayudarte.

Comment: que es el log ? después de mostrar los errores puedo ver que me esta dando el error HTTP405: MÉTODO INCORRECTO: el verbo HTTP usado no se admite.
POST

Comment: pero no veo ningún fallo de ruta ??